# Alternatives of spread syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays, cross-browser, spread-syntax

I see several uses of [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in a code. For example:

```
function tree2table(tree) {
    var children = tree["children"];
    if (children === undefined) return [];
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var child = children[i];
        var link = [child["name"], tree["name"], child["size"]];
        result.push(link);
        result.push(...tree2table(child))
    }
    return result
}
```

However, spread syntax is not supported in IE. Does anyone know what is the best way to change `result.push(...tree2table(child))` such that it becomes cross-browser and as efficient as before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Differenz

[`Array.prototype.push.apply(result, values)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) modifies instead of making a copy of an array

### Example

```js
const result = []
const values = ['a', 'b']
Array.prototype.push.apply(result, values)
console.log(result)
```

### Solution

```
function tree2table(tree) {
  var children = tree["children"];
  if (children === undefined) return [];
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var child = children[i];
    var link = [child["name"], tree["name"], child["size"]];
    result.push(link);
    Array.prototype.push.apply(result, tree2table(child))
  }
  return result
}
```

### Compatible

based on the [version information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/apply-method-function-javascript)

> Supported in the following document modes: Quirks, Internet Explorer 6 standards, Internet Explorer 7 standards, Internet Explorer 8 standards, Internet Explorer 9 standards, Internet Explorer 10 standards, Internet Explorer 11 standards.

Answer (score 8):

You could use [`function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), which takes the parameters as array.

> The **`apply()`** method calls a function with a given `this` value, and `arguments` provided as an array (or an array-like object).

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(result, tree2table(child));
```

Comment: Hi Nina. This is helpful ! How can I replace the spread operator in a set like `return [...new Set(array.map(item => item[prop]))];` ?

Comment: @Mike, why would you do that? `Set` is only available where spread syntax is available, too.